# Instance objects inside function which are not a member of a class

Tags: ruby

In the below example the function foo is not inside any class, in such a case "i is an instance of" which class?

```
def foo ()
  @i = "hello world"
end

foo
puts @i
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`foo` belongs to `Object`:

```
def foo
  @i = "hello world"
end

Object.instance_methods(false) # => [:foo]
method(:foo).owner # => Object
```